# Icon disappears from taskbar when changing window

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

I am trying to create a CRUD application where it has several windows. List customer, register customer, delete customer, edit customer.
For this I am trying to switch from window to another window, the problem is that when I switch the window the icon in the taskbar disappears. I must be doing it wrong. I am used to web applications, this is my first desktop application.

Taskbar icon:

[image]

Pseudo code:

**I've tried QStackedWidget but setting pages from the index doesn't look good when you have a lot of pages.**

**I updated my question using QMainWindow, I did not use QWindow because it does not support setLayout, for example.**

```py
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QDialog, QApplication, QDesktopWidget, QGridLayout, QLabel, QWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Main Window'
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 350
        self.height = 200
        self.InitUI()
        self.show()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)

        qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())

        layout = QGridLayout()

        label1 = QLabel('First Screen - Please wait...')
        label1.setFont(QFont("Times", 25, QFont.Bold))
        layout.addWidget(label1, 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.goToSecondScreen)

    def goToSecondScreen(self):
        w = SecondWindow(parent=self)
        w.show()
        self.hide()


class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.title = 'Second Window'
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 500
        self.InitUI()
        self.show()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)

        qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())

        layout = QGridLayout()

        label1 = QLabel('Second Screen - Please wait...')
        label1.setFont(QFont("Times", 25, QFont.Bold))
        layout.addWidget(label1, 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.goToThirdWindow)

    def goToThirdWindow(self):
        w = ThirdWindow(parent=self)
        w.show()
        self.hide()


class ThirdWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.title = 'Third Window'
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 500
        self.InitUI()
        self.show()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)

        qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())

        layout = QGridLayout()

        label1 = QLabel('ThirdWindow Screen')
        label1.setFont(QFont("Times", 25, QFont.Bold))
        layout.addWidget(label1, 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

as I've tested your code I saw that the taskbar cannot be found because you are creating QDialog instances, not a window, try creating an instance of a window instead not a QDialog instance

Comment: instead of approaching it, from window to window. 
my approach in creating desktop application is different.
i first create a PyQtTabWidget then hide the tabBar. 
you can just change tab for a new content

Comment: I've tried QStackedWidget but setting pages from the index doesn't look good when you have a lot of pages.